# How to select application type in GoogleCast dashboard?

Tags: ios, google-cast

I'm trying to integrate GoogleCast in my iOS application to play the videos on TV/Monitors. But when i'm trying to create an application id in Google cast dashboard, i'm very confused what to select. The options are like in the following screenshot.

[image]

Somebody please help me how to proceed

Thanks,
Raki.

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterDevice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out myself with the help of *KENdi* comment, Remote Display Receiver is the suitable option for my app purpose.